# How to reassign an object to the user with Role 'X'?

Tags: apex, user, loop, roles, if

We have a few users with Role 'X'. We need to reassign an object to one from these users, if it's created not by one of them. But my loop choose the last one and change owner even if owner is already correct (with Role 'X'). How can I fix it?

```
List<User> userList = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE UserRole.Name = 'X'];

     for(Obj__c obj: Trigger.new){
         for(User user : userList){
             if(obj.CreatedById != user.Id){
                 obj.OwnerId = user.Id;
             }
         }     
     }
```

Comment: Have you considered using a `Map<Id, User>`?

Comment: Same problem, even if I use break after `if(position.CreatedById == user.Id)`.

Comment: I think you should try stepping through your code logically and thinking about what's happening.  Sets have a method called `contains` that may help.

Comment: So what is the business rule for deciding which "role x" user to assign the records to?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Charles -- it would help to map out the business logic and take it step-by-step.  Let's walk through what you have currently:

- Get a list of all "role x" users.
- For every record in the trigger context...
- ...see if the record is created by the first "role x" user in the list
- ...If it isn't, set the record's owner to that user.

Then we go to the next user and do the same test: Did the user create this record?  If not, record ownership will be changed to this user...even if it was changed to the previous user in the list during the previous loop.

...and so on.

> But my loop chooses the last one and change owner even if owner is
>   already correct (with Role 'X')

The code is always looking at the record creator, not the record owner. It sounds like that's not what you want to be doing.

If you changed the test to look at the record owner instead, then you'd wind up assigning all the records to the last "role x" user in the list.  (In each loop through, the previous user will be the owner; the test will be true for "not owned by the current user," every time.)

Charles also mentioned using the "contains" method of the Set class.  To give you an idea what that would look like:

```
List<User> userList = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE UserRole.Name = 'X'];

Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();
for(User u : userList){
    userIds.add(u.Id);
}

for(Obj__c obj: Trigger.new){
    if(!userIds.contains(obj.CreatedById){
        obj.OwnerId = userList[0].Id;
    }
}
```

Now the problem isn't the code, but the business logic.  As you can see, all of the records are being assigned to the first "role x" user returned by the query.  I'm assuming that isn't what's required.

Once you know how to determine which user each record should be assigned to, you should be able to refactor this code to get where you need to be.